# how to append suffix to a token in spacy

Tags: nlp, spacy

Lets say the token is arrive.
How can I add a suffix -al to the token to become arrival using Spacy. I have looked at sense2vec, but it looks for the most similar words. I want to inflect the word by adding a suffix.